# Is the motherboard of HP Compaq Presario CQ5306UK compatible with Intel i5 or i7 processors?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Is the board compatible with any of the i5 or i7 chips, ?

I see on this page:

http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01981373

It mentions 6 compatible processors, but is it really only these that the Motherboard can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot use a i5 or i7, unfortunately, as i5 and i7's are either LGA 1366 (1st gen), 1156 (1st gen), 1155 (2nd & 3rd), 1150 (4th), or 2011 (4th). The motherboard only supports the LGA 775 socket of processors, which was right before the first generation of LGA 1366 'i' processors. Those 6 types listed under your link are the types of 775 processors it supports.

Unfortunately if you want an upgrade you'd have to purchase a new motherboard and a new processor. Given that it's an old pre-built, a new computer purchase in general may be the best option.